# How can package.json share the scripts field configuration in node multiple projects

Tags: javascript, npm

How can package.json share the scripts field configuration in node multiple projects

```
common-scripts

modules.export = {
  "dev": "npm run",
  "build": "run-p",
}

project 1


  "scripts": {
    "dev": "The dev command derived from common-scripts is executed here",
    "build": "The build command derived from common-scripts is executed here",
  },

project 2

  "scripts": {
    "dev": "The dev command derived from common-scripts is executed here",
    "build": "The build command derived from common-scripts is executed here",
  },
```

What can I do to achieve this effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options to start with:

**1. Lerna or a similar tool. Monorepo**

it'll contain `common-scripts` package and **shared scripts** across all packages out-of-the-box.

**2. Custom `common-script` module**

create a separate package for the `common-scripts` module and publish it to a private or public **npm** registry. Then use it as **dependencies** in other modules.

**3. Use a configuration management tool like Ansible or Chef**

use the `common-scripts` configuration for the `package.json` files and scripts. Then use the tool to apply that configuration to all of the projects in your infrastructure.

Comment: If it's option 2, and I have an npm package that contains the scripts object directive, how do I write scripts in package.json

Comment: One option:
Create a shared package: `{ "name": "common-scripts", "version": "1.0.0", "scripts": { "dev": "echo 1"} }`

Then publish it: `npm install && npm publish`

After that you can add it to other packages: `npm install common-scripts`. 

Then in scripts run: `npm run common-scripts dev`.

Another option: take a look at [workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/workspaces)

Comment: Thanks for your help, running `npm run common-scripts dev` directly will prompt `Missing script: "common scrips"`, whether it is` cd node_modules/commonscript && npm run dev` , but in this case, if there is a custom script, his path will point to node_modules/ The path to commonscrip, not the current project root path